# Create Sum Function with loop statement in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let me start with my table ;

these 3 table are main table .

club profile my customer information exists , in card transactions my customer transactions exists and cardtransationslog the transactions detail is exists .

This is my query logic : 
select people total points and select dateTime(card transactions log) when Their points is more than 12000

I tried this query , but i cant select the time in 3th table

```
SELECT CP.ClubProfileId, FirstName , LastName ,
sum(Points)
FROM ClubProfile CP JOIN CardTransaction CT 
ON CT.ClubProfileId = CP.ClubProfileId
JOIN CardTransactionLog CL
ON CL.CardTransactionLogId = CT.CardTransactionLogId
group by FirstName,LastName,cp.ClubProfileId
having sum(Points) > 12000
```

my main problem is that , with upper query  i cant find their time when the people total points when is more than 120000

In other sentence select their time when the points is more than 12000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get a dateTime from the card transactions table if it is enclosed in an appropriate aggregate function such as MIN or MAX.

```
SELECT CP.ClubProfileId, FirstName , LastName , max(CT.dateTime) as MaxDateTime
sum(Points)
FROM ClubProfile CP JOIN CardTransaction CT 
ON CT.ClubProfileId = CP.ClubProfileId
JOIN CardTransactionLog CL
ON CL.CardTransactionLogId = CT.CardTransactionLogId
group by FirstName,LastName,cp.ClubProfileId
having sum(Points) > 12000
```

If you don't want the min (earliest) or max (latest) you will need to provide some more information in your question.

**Edit**

The question is actually "find the dateTime when the points total exceeds 12,000". In order to find this we need some sort of running total of points. The SQLPerformance.com article [Best approaches for running totals](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals) suggests that cursors are often more efficient than set-based approaches for running totals so here is a cursor based solution.

```
create table dbo.ClubProfile (
ClubProfileId int not null,
FirstName varchar(10) not null,
LastName varchar(10) not null
)

create table dbo.CardTransaction (
ClubProfileId int not null,
CardTransactionLogId int not null,
Points int not null
)

create table dbo.CardTransactionLog (
CardTransactionLogId int not null,
[dateTime] datetime not null
)

insert dbo.ClubProfile values (1,'Rhys','Jones')
insert dbo.CardTransaction values (1, 1, 11000)
insert dbo.CardTransaction values (1, 2, 2000)
insert dbo.CardTransaction values (1, 3, 2000)
insert dbo.CardTransactionLog values (1, '2015-01-16')
insert dbo.CardTransactionLog values (2, '2015-01-17')
insert dbo.CardTransactionLog values (3, '2015-01-18')
go

-- create a working table to hold the dateTime and running sum of points for each ClubProfile
if (object_id('tempdb..#workingTable') is not null) drop table #workingTable
select ClubProfileId, cast(null as datetime) as dateTime, cast(0 as int) as SumPoints
    into #workingTable
    from dbo.ClubProfile

-- declare a cursor to iterate over all of the transactions.
declare cur cursor local static forward_only read_only for
    select CT.ClubProfileId, CT.Points, CL.dateTime
    from dbo.CardTransaction CT
    inner join dbo.CardTransactionLog CL on CL.CardTransactionLogId = CT.CardTransactionLogId
    order by CL.dateTime -- make sure this is the right order for your requirements

declare @ClubProfileId int
declare @Points int
declare @dateTime datetime

open cur
fetch next from cur into @ClubProfileId, @Points, @dateTime

while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin

    -- Update the working table with the current date and running sum of points
    -- if the current running sum of points is less than 12,000.
    update #workingTable set
        [dateTime] = @dateTime,
        SumPoints = SumPoints + @Points
    where
        ClubProfileId = @ClubProfileId and
        SumPoints < 12000 -- do you want "<" or "<="?

    fetch next from cur into @ClubProfileId, @Points, @dateTime
end

close cur
deallocate cur

-- select the results, note that SumPoints here is only the partial sum upto exceeding 12,000
select
    CP.ClubProfileId, CP.FirstName, CP.LastName, T.dateTime, T.SumPoints
from
    dbo.ClubProfile CP
        inner join #workingTable T on T.ClubProfileId = CP.ClubProfileId
```

Hope this helps,

Rhys

Comment: thank you for you attention , but  as i said i want the exact time when sum point is more than 12000 @Rhys joens

Comment: @user3087357 - OK, I misunderstood your requirement. To help me can you tell me which table the Points column is in.

Comment: yes sure , my 2th table that that name is card transactions.

Comment: my reputation is not enough to put image . can i have your email address and send it to you